# Moving UI with Screen Space - Camera (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move an image UI when Canvas is set on Screen Space - Camera

However, nothing seems to work. I've tried the following things:

```
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{

        Vector3 screenPoint = Input.mousePosition;
        screenPoint.z = 0.13f; //distance of the plane from the camera
        icon.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
    }
```

Makes the image move out of the screen instantly.

```
 public GameObject Target;
private EventTrigger _eventTrigger;
void Start ()
{
    _eventTrigger = GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
    _eventTrigger.AddEventTrigger(OnDrag, EventTriggerType.Drag);
}

void OnDrag(BaseEventData data)
{
    PointerEventData ped = (PointerEventData) data;
    Target.transform.Translate(ped.delta);
}
```

same story, image dissapires and moves out of the screen.

```
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Vector3 clickedPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    InventoryParent.transform.position = clickedPosition;
}
```

as the above.

Anyone has idea on how can I do accurate mouse dragging UI with Screen-Space Camera? Doing it with overlay works fine.

Comment: Canvas is screen space, event data and mouse position are in screen space, whyfor the `ScreenToWorldPoint`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your UI element RectTransform anchors to:

[image]

and add this script to your UI element object:

```
RectTransform rectT;

    void Start()
    {
        EventTrigger trigger = GetComponent<EventTrigger>();
        EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.Drag;
        entry.callback.AddListener((data) => { OnDragDelegate((PointerEventData)data); });
        trigger.triggers.Add(entry);
        rectT = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    public void OnDragDelegate(PointerEventData data)
    {
        rectT.anchoredPosition = data.position;

    }
```

You also need the `EventTrigger` component on your UI element object.